# LibXML internal and output encodings

Tags: c, xml, character-encoding, libxml2

I'm trying to write XML files with libxml2 in ISO-8859-1.
But from the documentation it seems that for each text node that I create I'll have to convert to UTF-8 which is libxml's internal encoding. Then when calling xmlSaveFormatFileEnc() libxml converts to the target encoding and adds the encoding attribute to the document.

Is this assumption correct?
For now my code goes roughly like this:

```
xmlNode *root_element = NULL, *node4 = NULL;
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;

doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST XML_DEFAULT_VERSION);
root_element = xmlNewDocNode(doc, NULL, BAD_CAST("root"),
                    NULL);
char * input_str = getLatin1Data();
isolat1ToUTF8(utf8_str, &file_size, input_str, &inlen);

node4 = xmlNewCDataBlock(doc, BAD_CAST list_content, xmlStrlen(BAD_CAST utf8_str));

xmlAddChild(root_element, node4);
xmlSaveFormatFileEnc("test_file.xml", doc, "UTF-8", 1);
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I'd really suggest rethinking your decision to use Latin-1. You'll probably regret it a few years (or even months) down the line, even for something as simple as wanting a Euro symbol in a string... There's a good reason UTF-8 is the default encoding for XML and anything modern.

Comment: Yes, now I'm only trying to get the UTF-8 conversion right. 
isolat1ToUTF8() doesn't want to help me though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is right. When `xmlChar` is expected, like in [`xmlNewCDataBlock`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNewCDataBlock), [`xmlNewText`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNewText), it is always UTF-8:

From `include/libxml/xmlstring.h` (libxml 2.8.0):

```
/**
 * xmlChar:
 *
 * This is a basic byte in an UTF-8 encoded string.
 * It's unsigned allowing to pinpoint case where char * are assigned
 * to xmlChar * (possibly making serialization back impossible).
 */
```