# xmlEscapeEntities : char out of range - Error

Tags: c, xml, linux, libxml2

Iam programing in C and using libxml for generating XML file but iam getting the following 
error : xmlEscapeEntities : char out of range. I am picking the data from database and storing it in the tags that iam generating (during generation of XML file).

I want to know why iam getting this error . What is the main cause of this? 
Code spinet :

```
     xmlNodeSetContent(temp_id,(const xmlChar *)details[nCl1+0]);
            632                                 xmlNodeSetContent(temp_id2, (const xmlChar *)details[nCl1+1]);
            633                                 xmlNodeSetContent(temp_id3,(const xmlChar *)details[nCl1+2]);
            634                                 xmlNodeSetContent(temp_id4,(const xmlChar *)details[nCl1+3]);
            635                                 xmlNodeSetContent(temp_id5,(const xmlChar *)details[nCl1+4])

;
```

Here variable "details" has the values picked from database.
This is the part of the code where iam getting this error.

Comment: Maybe if you gave the complete error together with the (relevant!) code that causes the error, we might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the string you supply as `xmlChar *` is not a correct UTF-8 string. So it's probably encoded in other standard and you need to convert it to UTF-8 first. You may use for example [iconv library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

See a [question about `xmlChar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164815/libxml-internal-and-output-encodings#12347869)